# Are there fundamental bugs in pthreads mutex implementation?

Tags: multithreading, posix, mutex

One day I found an interesting article regarding possible bugs in pthreads mutex implementation, followed by a discussion:

https://lwn.net/Articles/575460

My current knowledge of pthreads library (and multithreaded programming in general) is too poor for me to understand most of the discussion, but I must admit it leads me to some pretty disturbing conclusions. Does it mean that current implementation of pthreads mutex is indeed seriously flawed and, as a consequence, Linux kernel (which undoubtedly relies heavily on multithreaded code) may be swarmed with critical bugs originating from that flaw? I always assumed code as basic, low-level and fundamental as that of basic synchronization primitives such as mutexes had been thoroughly tested (or even proved to be correct). Instead, we suddenly find out there's a "special case" everyone failed to notice for years and no one, including Linus Torvalds, can tell for sure how frequently it may occur in kernel code.
Sounds quite terrifying, doesn't it?

Anyway, what's the current status of the problem and possible resolution of it (the article is from late 2013)? Has the mutex implementation been changed to cover the omitted special case? Or has the library documentation (POSIX standard?) been changed to strengthen conditions under which it's safe to use mutexes? Has anything been done at all? Does it even make sense to learn pthreads library if it's very likely corrupt and unreliable? Or is my whole understanding of the subject wrong and there's no issue at all?

Comment: The linked discussion has nothing to do with POSIX mutexes.  POSIX mutexes are *user-space* objects.  The discussion is about *kernel* locks that run in *kernel* space.  Also I suspect that the fundamental bug isn't in the kernel lock, it's in the way it's used - the memory in question is freed *after* the lock is released, which means a second thread waiting on the lock would get the lock, increment the ref count in question, and then try to use memory that's already been freed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Btw most mutexes (including POSIX and C++11 ones) explicitly allow usage described in that article.

Comment: @Ivan I'm not sure what your point is.  Every version of the C, C++, and POSIX standards ever published can't protect against buggy code.  Did you read the entire article?  It's pretty much *impossible* to protect any memory with a lock located inside that memory, whether that lock is a POSIX mutex, a Linux kernel lock, or a C++11 mutex.  Such memory can't be freed while the lock is held, and there's ***NO*** way to prevent another thread from waiting to acquire the lock that a thread is about to free after it releases the lock.  It's a bug.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are not reading my post. The usage shown in that article _is correct_ for POSIX and C++11 mutexes. And it is not impossible, but is actually very easy to guarantee that - mutex should not be accessed after atomic instruction that unlocks it succeeds. Following `futex` wake call in a possible deallocated memory region is a valid behavior and is one source of spurious wake-ups of `futex` wait operation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Related glibc bug [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13690).

Comment: @Ivan *The usage shown in that article is correct for POSIX and C++11 mutexes.* Yes, the usage is allowed by POSIX and C++11.  So what?  Both C++11 and POSIX allow you to write crap code that fails on a NULL pointer dereference or a divide-by-zero.  So it's ***BUGGY***.  Again, you can not protect memory from being freed with a lock located within that memory.  Period.

Comment: @Ivan *Related glibc bug here.*  Again, so what?  That's a ***BUG*** in the Linux implementation of a POSIX mutex.  It's also been fixed for over two years.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You said "fundamental bug isn't in the kernel lock, it's in the way it's used" which implies usage was incorrect. But usage was very typical for a mutex. Then you said "you can not protect memory from being freed with a lock located within that memory" - which is also incorrect.

Comment: @Ivan *Then you said "you can not protect memory from being freed with a lock located within that memory" - which is also incorrect.*  Oh, you posting examples of how you can do that safely is going to be good.  1) You can't free memory containing a mutex when the mutex is locked, 2) You can't prevent other threads from waiting to lock the mutex.  Please, read the comments:  https://lwn.net/Articles/575460/  "If the only protection for a piece of memory is a lock inside that piece of memory, life is hard."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164931/discussion-between-ivan-and-andrew-henle).

Answer (score 1):

Mutex usage shown in that article *is valid* for POSIX and C++11 mutexes. Glibc had similar [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13690) which is now fixed.

I think every synchronization primitive in glibc had similar bug at some point. Here some (all fixed now):

- [Bug 13065](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13065) Race condition in pthread barriers
- [Bug 12674](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12674) - `sem_post`/`sem_wait` race causing sem_post to return `EINVAL`

I am not sure what is the state of it now, but it is very likely that at least shared POSIX primites are not fully conformant.

Musl libc tries to provide correct implementation of POSIX primitives. This is the reason why `pthread_barrier_wait` on shared barrier shares global in-process lock with `MAP_FIXED` `mmap` call. And I am not sure even this fixes all issues. Would be nice to know how glibc handles this, very likely it doesn't, so this might be an example of a "fundamental bug".

You might want to check musl author's profile  - [Rich Felker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) - and his question list here to find many issues.

Answer (score 0):

Pthreads is Posix threads and is worth knowing independently of any particular implementation. 
Linux is not the only one. Pthreads is tried and tested and works very well even there.

If you read the article carefully the issue only manifests in certain circumstances. You have to have one thread spinning waiting to acquire the lock just at the moment that the lock holder wakes up a third thread also waiting on the lock. Furthermore the reason its unsafe here is that the actions of the 'spinning' thread cause a problem for the third thread as it thinks its safe to free the object containing the mutex when it clearly isn't if the third thread is going to use it.

In fact the problem isn't so much in the mutex implementation at all rather than in how it is being used, though certainly a fix to make it safe to use it this way would be welcome.
It seems to be of concern to the Kernel community because this issue can manifest in a coding pattern used quite widely (i.e. ref counting to decide when its safe to delete something).
You could check the Kernel change history to see if there has been one if you are interested.

Disclaimer: I am only peripherally familiar with these issues. Someone more familiar with mutex implementations and the Kernel might be able to guide you better.